# Как правильно разделить разработку веб-проекта на юзер-стори?

Tags: agile, проекты, scrum, менеджмент

Пытаемся в команде внедрить гибкую методологию разработки веб-проектов. До этого работали по классическому waterfall (Каскадная модель), но проекты тянуться в сроках.

В данный момент пришла задача на перенос крупного проекта с одной платформы(asp.net) на другую(php). И у меня стал вопрос, каким образом правильно подойти к поставлению юзер-стори проекта.

Проект должен пройти в любом случае через:

- разработку интерфейса
- верстку
- программную часть
- админ-панель
- api

Коллеги, прошу вашей помощи :)

Принцип работы по методологии сложился полностью, затык именно в юзер-стори(хотя может я и ошибаюсю)

Comment: _До этого работали по классическому waterfall (Каскадная модель), но проекты тянуться в сроках._ -а вы уверены, что проблема в парадигме, а не в команде?

Comment: если переносите/меняете серверную часть, то для чего "разработка интерфейса" и "верстка"? а переходите с asp.net web forms?

Comment: @Grundy вы знаете, я наверное не так выразился. Просто проект разработка идет 1-2-3 мес и не видно результата руководству. Да и потом много проблем слышим от пользователей, это не так должно работать...

Comment: @Stack первая версия проекта была разработана в 2010 году, за это время сайт устарел вот и меняем.

Comment: @АлександрПарфенов _"была разработана в 2010 году, за это время сайт устарел"_ -- а не проще перенести на asp.net mvc, owin? части кода можно будет использовать без изменений

Answer (score 1):

Пользовательские истории -- это не конечные задачи которые вы, как руководитель проекта, должны сформировать, положить в беклог, оценить с командой, а потом вытягивать в тот или иной спринт.

Пользовательская история пишется аналитиками, заказчиком, кем угодно, но не ПМ-ом. Вам, по идее, должны предоставить законченую, конкретизированную юзер-стори, после чего она разбивается на задачи (дизайн, разработка, копирайтинг и т.д.).

Довольно часто реализация одной пользовательской истории совпадает по времени с одним спринтом.